# Get hostname to show fqdn without --fqdn

Tags: linux, hostname

I would like the hostname command to show the fqdn by default on CentOS Linux.  What must be done to get this behavior?  I am not looking to alias hostname to 'hostname --fqdn'  I am looking to modify the system in a way that the gethostbyname calls, or whatever is used to get hostname get the entire fqdn ala host.example.bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `FQDN hostname` to `/etc/sysconfig/network`:

```
HOSTNAME=host.example.bar
```

After a system restart the `hostname` command (without any options) should display the `FQDN`.

```
[user@host ~]# hostname
host.example.bar
```

This works on CentOS 5/6.

Comment: Maybe I was just missing the restart then.  Thanks I will try it.

Comment: That was it.  How silly of me, I am just so rarely required to reboot.  I assume there is a way to do this without rebooting.  That would be nice to know how to do.  service hostname doesn't seem to exist, perhaps network service restart?